# What would be the correct query for this?

Tags: sql, excel

[image: Task I'm supposed to do/finish]

This is what I have, but it returns a very vague error in Excel VBA.

```
SELECT Customers.Company, Orders.Order_Date, Orders.Shipped_Date FROM Customers, Orders WHERE Customers.ID = Orders.Order_ID
```

[image: Vague Error in VBA]

Comment: Your where is incorrect. It should be Customers.ID = Orders.Customer_id. But not sure if it would solve your VB error

Comment: What database is used?

Comment: Why is Excel even involved?

Comment: Sorry for the late replies, but MSAccess DB is being used, and It's for a VBA script in Excel. Solution below worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not linking PK and FK fields in WHERE clause. Should use JOIN clause anyway.

Field names in tables show using spaces, yet code uses underscores. This is source of error message. When field names have spaces or special characters or are reserved words, enclose in `[ ]`. Strongly advise not to use those features in naming convention.

```
SELECT Company, [Order Date], [Shipped Date] 
FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.ID = Orders.[Customer ID];
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed and will note the syntax for fieldnames with spaces for future projects.